# Bibliography - issue - APA6

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

I am failing to understand following problem with my bibliography....citation in text works fine, citations in bibiography work fine too, except one problem: I want it like "Planen und Problemlösen: Überlegungen zur ...." but it results in "Planen und Problemlösen: überlegungen zur ....". I have no idea how to force LaTeX giving me a big Ü instead of a tiny ü.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}%mod.
\usepackage[locale=US]{siunitx}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}

\begin{document}
Hello, this is my cite: \cite{Funke.1990}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In my `Literatur.bib`:

```
@Article{Funke.1990,
Title  = {{P}lanen und {P}robleml{\"o}sen: {\"{U}}berlegungen zur 
neuropsychologischen {D}iagnostik von {B}asiskompetenzen beim {P}lanen},
Author = {Funke, Joachim and Glodowski, Anne-Simone},
Journal= {Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Neuropsychologie},
Year  = {1990},
Pages = {139--148},
Volume = {2}
}
```

Comment: It's curious, because the `.bbl` file has `Überlegungen`, with a capital `Ü`.

Comment: Absolutely correct, thanks a lot, shall I delete this posting?

Comment: We can mark your question as duplicate of the question linked to above, so you do not have to delete it.